# Kubernetes DNS not working on local Ubuntu 18.04 environment

Tags: kubernetes, dns, ubuntu-18.04

I trying to deploy Kubernetes system on my local computer (Ubuntu 18.04) and have some problems with the DNS service (I can't talk with headless services through their DNS name).

I use minikube for running the cluster and the version is -

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:30:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:22:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The headless service -

```
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP             67m
zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None         <none>        2888/TCP,3888/TCP   3m58s
```

The pods -

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
zookeeper-statefulset-0   1/1     Running   1          57m
zookeeper-statefulset-1   1/1     Running   1          56m
zookeeper-statefulset-2   1/1     Running   1          54m
```

DNS service endpoint which not exists -  (`kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system`)

```
NAME       ENDPOINTS   AGE
kube-dns               68m
```

The DNS pods (not ready) -

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6955765f44-gv42p   0/1     Running   1          58m
coredns-6955765f44-rfkm2   0/1     Running   1          58m
```

and the logs of DNS pod is -

> [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 =
>   4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7 CoreDNS-1.6.5 linux/amd64, go1.13.4,
>   c2fd1b2 [INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes" [INFO]
>   plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes" [INFO] plugin/ready:
>   Still waiting on: "kubernetes" E0221 12:50:23.090626       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090668       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090671       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout I0221 12:50:23.090594       1
>   trace.go:82] Trace[146678255]: "Reflector
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98
>   ListAndWatch" (started: 2020-02-21 12:49:53.090061147 +0000 UTC
>   m=+0.011664556) (total time: 30.000405618s): Trace[146678255]:
>   [30.000405618s] [30.000405618s] END E0221 12:50:23.090626       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090626       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090626       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout I0221 12:50:23.090644       1
>   trace.go:82] Trace[653875127]: "Reflector
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98
>   ListAndWatch" (started: 2020-02-21 12:49:53.090057185 +0000 UTC
>   m=+0.011660587) (total time: 30.00054106s): Trace[653875127]:
>   [30.00054106s] [30.00054106s] END I0221 12:50:23.090654       1
>   trace.go:82] Trace[1501712764]: "Reflector
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98
>   ListAndWatch" (started: 2020-02-21 12:49:53.090052023 +0000 UTC
>   m=+0.011655434) (total time: 30.000437703s): Trace[1501712764]:
>   [30.000437703s] [30.000437703s] END E0221 12:50:23.090668       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090668       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090668       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090671       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090671       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout E0221 12:50:23.090671       1
>   reflector.go:125]
>   pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98:
>   Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get
>   https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout [INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting
>   on: "kubernetes" [INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
>   [INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"

I tried running -

```
kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28 dns-test --restart=Never --rm
/ # nslookup headless.default.svc.cluster.local
```

and got -

```
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'headless.default.svc.cluster.local'
```

I don't even know where to start to fix that. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

I think I understand what is causing the problem but I do not understand why it is happening.
The problem seems to be happening after the FireWall is activated. For some reason, the core-dns pods can't run and get stuck in a ready state. After I turned off the FireWall by running - 
`sudo ufw disable`
The core-dns pods state has changed to `Running` and the service now has endpoint addresses.

```
 kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28 dns-test --restart=Never --rm
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup  zookeeper-headless.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      zookeeper-headless.default
Address 1: 172.17.0.4 zookeeper-statefulset-1.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 172.17.0.5 zookeeper-statefulset-0.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 3: 172.17.0.6 zookeeper-statefulset-2.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
```

.

```
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
kube-dns   172.17.0.2:53,172.17.0.3:53,172.17.0.2:53 + 3 more...   34m
```

.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS           12m
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-2d8md         1/1     Running   4          34m
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-n2gcp         1/1     Running   4          34m
```

Comment: provide logs of core dns pods

Comment: No logs, you just copy/paste the output of `kubectl describe` of the pod.

Comment: what cni are you using ? flannel or something else? What is the pod cidr you have given? How did you setup the cluster, kubeadm or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it and added the logs @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: I only use ```sudo minikube start --vm-drive=none``` for starting the cluster  @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: I didn't install any CNI when I installed the minikube

Comment: You're trying to reach `headless.default.svc.cluster.local` but I can't see any service with this name in your services list. Please try reaching `zookeeper-headless` with `$ nslookup zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking I understand what is causing the problem but I do not understand why it is happening.
The problem seems to be happening after the FireWall is activated. For some reason, the core-dns pods can't run and get stuck in a ready state. After I turned off the FireWall by running -

`sudo ufw disable`

The core-dns pods state has changed to `Running` and the service now has endpoint addresses.

```
 kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28 dns-test --restart=Never --rm
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup  zookeeper-headless.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      zookeeper-headless.default
Address 1: 172.17.0.4 zookeeper-statefulset-1.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 172.17.0.5 zookeeper-statefulset-0.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 3: 172.17.0.6 zookeeper-statefulset-2.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
```

.

```
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
kube-dns   172.17.0.2:53,172.17.0.3:53,172.17.0.2:53 + 3 more...   34m
```

.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS           12m
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-2d8md         1/1     Running   4          34m
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-n2gcp         1/1     Running   4          34m
```

Comment: Have you notices that in your first question you are trying to reach a name that doesn't exist and after the edit you are reaching the correct name?

Comment: I noticed that I was wrong in the name and then tried with the right name, that was not the problem.
The coredns pods got stuck in a ```Ready``` state and there was no endpoint to service until I turned off the firewall.